# Objective-C UIImageView Collision

Tags: objective-c, xcode, collision-detection

I want to detect a collision between 2 UIImageviews.
The problem is that i dont want to use `CGRectIntersectsRect(Image.frame, Image2.frame)`, because the images are no rectangles.
So if i use that there is a collision where there is no collision, just because of the rectangle frames of the image.
Thank you for your help!
Peace

Comment: Doing with UIKit would be half a nightmare and a lot expensive. The best idea would be to get help from a framework like Cocos2D.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i implement the Cocos2D framework in my XCode project?

Comment: That's a bit too broad I think. You should start your own research on that.